# Django : How to render an HTML file from outside templates folder

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I would like to know if there is a way in Django te render HTML files from outside the template directory.

In my case, I have a app/docs folder which contains my static documentation HTML files. I tried everything I found so far but I always end up with a `TemplateDoesNotExist` exception.

```
Tree:
  project
  |__app_name
     |__templates
     |  |__app_name
     |     |__templates
     |
     |__docs
        |__templates_to_render
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `TEMPLATES` [configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#configuration) in your Django Settings:

> DIRS defines a list of directories where the engine should look for template source files, in search order.

> APP_DIRS tells whether the engine should look for templates inside installed applications. Each backend defines a conventional name for the subdirectory inside applications where its templates should be stored.

So, the `APP_DIRS` will already look inside your templates folder inside your app_name folder, and with `DIRS` you can set your `docs` folder to be inside or outside your app_name folder. I prefer outside, like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'docs')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]
```

Your tree should look like this to work:

```
Tree:
  project
  |__app_name
     |__templates
     |  |__app_name
     |     |__templates
     |
     docs
     |__templates_to_render
```